# How can I index multiple date intervals in neo4j?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, neo4j

here is my problem: I need to index into neo4j a node with a property that is composed of an arbitrary number of date intervals, for example:

Node: 10
Dating: 1990/03/14 - 1994/04/23, 1999/12/12 - 2005/04/06

Node: 11
Dating: 1890/10/18 - 1950/05/15, 1970/06/08 - 1988/05/11, 1993/06/09 - 2010/07/04

I need to be able to query with a single date and find all the nodes where the queried date is within one of the intervals, so for the preceding example if I query for 1995/08/13 I want to get only Node 11 and not 10 in the results.

The solution I'm considering is to "flat" the intervals to a single interval in the index and than scan the results to remove false positive results, so for the preceding example I would index the data like:

Node: 10
Dating-low: 1990/03/14
Dating-high: 2005/04/06

Node: 11
Dating-low: 1890/10/18
Dating-high: 2010/07/04

Querying for 1995/08/13 will return both the nodes, but than I will discard Node 10 by consulting the actual date intervals stored in the node. It is a solution, but It will possibly slow down my queries, so I would like to ask: is there a more efficient solution? Said solution is possible using only the indexing API that neo4j exposes?
Thank you.

**Edit**
Let me add more details to explain my problem. First, I usually can't use a query based on the graph structure (a cypher query) because the data that I save on the nodes are different than the data I index (don't ask me why, it's long to explain), to make a simple example for a node I could have the data:

Node: 10
100_1_fv: NodeName
101_0_fv: 1990/03/14 - 1994/04/23

And in the lucene index:

Node: 10
Name: NodeName
Dating-low: 19900314
Dating-high: 19940423

So If I can I would restrict the queries to the lucene index. Still one of the answers (the only one at the moment) gave me the idea to do a first query in the lucene index, and than do a second query using cypher to refine the results of the first query exploiting the graph structure. Please let me know if it's a valid approach or there's a better one.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is good practice to separate those date properties into separate nodes and relationships.

So if node 10, 11 represent a Person and the intervals represent Employment periods (not likely in your case, but as an example) then you would create nodes and relationships:

(Person)-[:employed_in]->(Job)

Where 1 person has multiple jobs, connected by the "employed_in" relationship. For the dates you also use further nodes (not properties) as explained here:

http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/02/modeling-multilevel-index-in-neoj4.html

This is more modeling up front but means that you can write and test Cypher queries on your data without having to drop to the Java API, which makes it easier to query the data to check your data model.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I edited the question to add more details about my problem, hope to have your opinion on it.